# typescript: instanceof not working with immutable.js types

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

We are trying to update our project from typescript2.4 to typescript3.2. We stumbled upon the following problem with immutable.js.

Previously just using `if(x instanceof Immutable.Iterable)` meant that in the `if` block the type of `x` was `Immutable.Iterable<any, any>`. However, after updating typescript, the inferred type of x is `{}`.

Code snippet

[image]

Wrong type inferrence

[image]

It would be really nasty to fix all the errors by using `x as Immutable.Iterable<any, any>`.

I guess the problem lies with immutable.js because any other types are inferred correctly in the `if` block.

P.S. I know about the fact that `instanceof` is not always trustworthy (https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/450#issuecomment-107238770) but using `Immutable.Iterable.isIterable()` doesn't provide the type support that we need (since the variable is still of type `any`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a type guard:

```
const isIterable = (argument: any): argument is Iterable<any> =>
  Symbol.iterator in argument
```

Usage:

```
declare const foo: number | Iterable<number>;

if (isIterable(foo)) {
  console.log(...foo);
}
```

> The version of `immutable` I have installed is `4.0.0-rc.12`. It
>   doesn't expose a class called `Iterable`. Instead, it relies on the
>   `Iterable` interface built-in the standard JavaScript library.